# space between images in thumbnail for ipad

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, uiscrollview

I create Thumbnail photo with scrollview for ipad, here is the code:

```
// load all the images from bundle and add them to the scroll view
NSUInteger i;
for (i = 1; i <= kNumImages; i++)
{
    NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"image%d.jpg", i];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
    UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:image];


}



 - (void)layoutScrollImages
{
UIImageView *view = nil;
NSArray *subviews = [scrollView1 subviews];

// reposition all image subviews in a horizontal serial fashion
CGFloat curXLoc = 0;
for (view in subviews)
{
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]] && view.tag > 0)
    {
        CGRect frame = view.frame;
        frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
        view.frame = frame;

        curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth);
    }
}

}
```

rightnow I have all images in UIScrollView that they are next to each other, I want to have some space between each images like this picture

[image]

would you please give me some hint that how can I add space between these images?

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth) + kDifferenceBetweenImages;
```

and define kDifferenceBeteweenIMages accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, do you know how can I add space between up and done part of my images in my uiscrollview?

Answer (score 0):

Use UICollectionView instead.  Much easier to achieve what you want and will work better too.

It even has a property for the space between each cell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
CGRect frame = view.frame;
frame.origin = CGPointMake(curXLoc, 0);
frame.size.height = //put height;
frame.size.width = //put width;
frame.origin.y = //put y;
view.frame = frame;
curXLoc += (kScrollObjWidth) + 15;
```